# Edit form for custom loop post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

So, I have a custom loop post.

On the page, I have 10 posts as below:

```
<?php   
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'mail',
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'mail_cat' => '',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',      
    );      
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );  
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
?>
```

Each post gets title, content and price based on the `data-mail_id` as below:

```
<div data-mail_id="' . esc_attr( $mail->id ) . '">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php echo $mail->get_price_html(); ?>
</div>
```

Now, how can I add an edit form (`<form>`) to edit the post contents?

I am guessing I need following:

1. Get the `<form>` with the targeted `post-mail_id` data such as title.
2. Change the contents of the post
3. Submit the change which will update the data for that specific `post-mail_id`.

What do you guys think?

**EDIT 1:**

Well, I am not sure if this is correct, but it is a start :p

```
<form role="form" method="post">                    
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update_post_'. get_the_ID(), 'update_post_nonce' ); ?>                           
    <div id="title_change">                                         
        <input type="text" id="post_title" name="post_title" value="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>"></input>              
        <input  type="submit" name="update" type="submit" ></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

So, now what? lol

So, I can show the original title in the input field.
I am not sure how the change can be submitted and be updated.

Comment: Yeah you should do that, then come back with an actual question.

Comment: I added the form. I understand how to put the form and show the original content for the users to edit. Once the submit button is clicked, how is it supposed to get updated ? confused..

Comment: Not familiar with wordpress but i'm sure there are methods available to update certain posts. If not you'll have to update them yourself, again, i have no idea how wp posts are saved. Edit: simple google search provided the required [method](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)